# Best way for Lua script to call a C shared lib?

Tags: lua

I come from more of a Python and CTYPES background...and am trying to work out the best way to call a standard C shared lib from Lua script.

I have heard of "Alien" (http://alien.luaforge.net/), but am not sure how current it is? Meaning it is updated regulary?

For example, I know that thier is an SQLite Lua library but let's say I wanted to call the SQLite shared lib that is created when I compile SQLIte?

So for example: In my case the lib is in /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so

If I write a little dummy script just to see if it can load the lib

```
require "libsqlite3"

print "hello"
```

I get the following error:

```
debian@debian:~/Desktop/SQLite Test$ lua sqlite_test.lua
lua: error loading module 'libsqlite3' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/libsqlite3.so':
    /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/libsqlite3.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_libsqlite3
stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    sqlite_test.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
debian@debian:~/Desktop/SQLite Test$
```

Does this mean that Lua cannot call shared libs "out the box" and that I HAVE TO use something like Alien?

I know I can also code the shared lib in such a way that it includes the Lua header files and I can make "Lua functions"...I was just *hoping* I could call shared libs that are "standard" on the box.

And help or advise would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Thanks

Lynton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua cannot call C libraries out of the box. It does not ship with libffi, and as such doesn't work like ctypes.

Historically, lua is embedded into an application which in turn will add to the lua tables the needed functions and provide the lua stack manipulation to pass and return parameters.

Alien is a libffi adaptation and will work.

Comment: Do you know if Alien is used widely in production? I assume it is rock solid like Python CTYPES?

Comment: I looked into it, and it seems that Python ctypes also uses libffi, which is what Alien uses in Lua. Therefore, it should be as "rock solid" as Python ctypes :)

Answer (score 4):

Like Yann said, Lua cannot call C libraries by default. The usual practice is to expose the wanted API by means of creating a binding library. There are several places, where you can look for existing library bindings for Lua, like [the wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings), [LuaRocks](http://www.luarocks.org/) or [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/).

If no bindings exist, you may try to use [Alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/) to bind straight to C libraries using libffi.

For your example - Sqlite3, there are at least 2 bindings:

- generic SQL binding - [LuaSql](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/), provides binding to Sqlite3, MySQL, Oracle...
- specialized binding - [Lua-Sqlite3](http://www.mroth.net/lua-sqlite3/)