# User32.dll function call with Lua

Tags: dll, lua

How can I use a Lua DLL call function to send the message `EM_REDO` to the User32 dynamic link library, using the `SendMessageA` function? I have actually checked the Microsoft site and studied the parameters and any further information required, which I have applied, but I still don't get how to implement this in Lua. I actually think the problem is how to define the message `EM_REDO` with a constant value. I believe an attempt to get this working will help most programmers coding in Lua, since `user32.dll` in Windows comes with many functions.

Comment: Have you looked at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162161/best-way-for-lua-script-to-call-a-c-shared-lib?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [winapi module for Lua](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi), both because it may already handle what you need and because you can see how this is all done under the hood. As far as I remember, it supports both `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` calls.